# Confusion in Integrating?

Tags: integration

So here is the problem
                               $I= \int$$\frac{sin^4x}{sin^4x + cos^4x}dx$

solution

Using $sin^2x$=$\frac{1}{2}(1-cos2x)$  and $cos^2x=\frac{1}{2}(1+cos2x)$

we can write 
 $I=\int\frac{(1-cos2x)^2}{2(1+cos^2x)}dx$
             =$\frac{1}{2}\int[1-\frac{2cos2x}{2-sin^22x}]$
my question is how did the transformation take place in the last step from  $\int\frac{(1-cos2x)^2}{2(1+cos^2x)}dx$ to $\frac{1}{2}\int[1-\frac{2cos2x}{2-sin^22x}]$ can anyone explain me briefly

Thank's for the help

Akash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin^4x}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}$$

$$=\frac14\frac{(2\sin^2x)^2}{(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x}\text{ using }\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$$

$$=\frac14\frac{(1-\cos2x)^2}{1-\frac{\sin^22x}2}\text{ using  } \sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$$

$$=\frac{1+\cos^22x-2\cos2x}{2(2-\sin^22x)}$$

$$=\frac{1+1-\sin^22x-2\cos2x}{2(2-\sin^22x)}$$

$$=\frac12\left(1-\frac{2\cos2x}{(2-\sin^22x)}\right)$$